# I am not able to pull the release branch details for Git using Git Rest API

Tags: git, github

I am trying to pull the release branch details from git source using git rest api. But I am not able to pull any of the release branches .

Example url : https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches

Please help me to find out the proper url

Comment: Can you show the commands you're using? What about the current and expected output?

Comment: Git itself does not have a REST API. GitHub and GitLab do, but the two are different. You should pick the one you care about.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I used the command GET https://github.com/api/v3/repos/:repo/branches through postman. I want all the release branch details which starts with the branch name as release. But don't see any of those branch details when I tried pulling the data using above url

Comment: Releases are not branches, see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository

Comment: I tried to pull releases details also, but we are getting response as blank. I have used the github.com/api/v3/repos/:repo/releases url to pull the details. Any idea why I am getting response as blank.

Comment: With GET github.com/api/v3/repos/:repo/branches url , I am not able to fetch all the branch details. Please help me in this